# Android Pay - Sample app not working ("Not available here")

Tags: android, android-pay

I am trying to run the Android Pay sample app (https://github.com/android-pay/androidpay-quickstart), but keep getting error messages. Here are they:

A pop-up with title *"Not available here"* and message saying *"This card isn't available with Android Pay in this app. Please try a different card."*

[image]

When you press *"Ok"* in that pop-up, you can see the other error message:

*"Unrecognized app. Please make sure that you trust this app before proceeding"*:

[image]

And before anyone asks, yes, I have followed the instructions on github to generate the keys and put the Base64 version of the public key inside ids.xml.

Here is my environment:

1. I am outside the US (I need to develop this for some customers in the US)
2. I am doing everything "network related" through a VPN pointing to the US (that is how I installed the Android Pay app too, otherwise it would not show up in the PlayStore for download).
3. I am faking my GPS coordinates to be inside the US.
4. I **don't** have a SIM card on my phone.
5. I am using `WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST`, but I have also tried with the deprecated `WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX` and `WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_STRICT_SANDBOX` without success.
6. I've added a genuine Discover credit card from the US to the Android Pay app.

I did noticed, however, that if I check the details of the Discover card I am using on the Android Pay app, the option "Change Google payments PIN" is there:

[image]

and, according to [this link](https://support.google.com/androidpay/answer/6291028?vid=1-635785656069772392-4179255051), if you see the message *"Change Google payments PIN"* then your card is not yet supported. However, this goes against the error messages above. They seem to indicate another problem.

Does anybody have any clue? The same error messages appear to me when I try to implement Android Pay in my own app.

Comment: Is there anything about your device which could be detected as outside the U.S, independent of the Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the card I was using was the problem. I tried with a different card and now it works. It looks like Google allows you to enter not yet supported cards so they can let you know once they are supported.

The error messages are confusing and don't give any indication that the problem is with the card.

Answer (score 0):

Android Pay is not available for all cards and for all country , so that why it's not working you can find the list for card and country.

I am mentioning following steps these may be useful for you.

Step 1:- If you are not in us and you want to use android pay then you should have a us registered email id (You can make us email id with help of gmail ) then you can download android pay .

Step2: You can register you credit card in android pay now a days few credit cards are supported by android pay you can try with Visa, Master Card, American Express cards and other cards which support the android pay.

Step 3: Implement following points https://developers.google.com/android-pay/diagrams .

If you have some problem then comment me.